# How can i add the windows boot loader on Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I had a dual boot system with windows 10 and PopOS (Linux) . Both on seperate SSDs. The Linux SSD was hard drive encrypted.
I wanted to change the linux distro to Ubuntu. When prompted to 'install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10' i couldn't choose the Linux SSD as installation device.
I thought it had something to do with the harddrive encryption so i went to disconnect the windows
drive and installed Ubuntu on the linux drive to overwrite the harddrive encryption.
The Problem now is, that i don't have the Windows boot loader anymore. When i try to reinstall Ubuntu i can't install it alongside windows because it isn't detected and i have now Ubuntu and Windows on seperate drives but can't acces Windows.
I couldn't find any solution that doesn't need a new installation of windows to get them together in GRUB.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are both installs UEFI/gpt or both very old BIOS/MBR? Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI  boot mode to gpt partitioned drives since 2012. So most hardware is UEFI. But how you boot install media UEFI or BIOS/CSM/Legacy is then how it installs. If hardware is UEFI, then both installs should be UEFI. If not sure how you installed:  `[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo EFI || echo Legacy`

Comment: FYI:  You didn't provide any Ubuntu product/release details, so we can provide specific advice on your installation due to lack of specific details  (*the release tells us the age of your software stack allowing us to better guess potential issues*)

Comment: If Ubuntu was installed in the same BIOS or UEFI mode Windows uses run `sudo update-grub`